# (dual boot)Windows crashing on startup after recent ubuntu update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

I started using ubuntu for a few weeks and I am learning it bit by bit... On my lenovo laptop(ideapad 720s) i have windows 10(20H2) and ubuntu(20.04.1)on dual boot. Both were working fine for a few weeks. After a recent update on ubuntu(i can't remember what it was but it required a reboot) windows won't boot, it just shows the lenovo startup logo and nothing happens. But ubuntu boots up fine. I still haven't tried anything at this point. Any help would be appreciated if anything can be done to fix this(grub version is 2.04, fast boot disabled, laptop uses UEFI)

Comment: Have you tried boot-repair, https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-repair-the-grub2-boot-loader-on-linux/ ? Also, if you've made disk images, you can restore the EFI partition.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik do i have to repair the grub or use the windows boot-repair? Because i'm not sure if this is the grub's problem or a problem for windows

Comment: Try repairing grub first. BTW, Macrium Reflect, and I'm sure other image apps, have an option to restore disk bootability. Use whatever imaging software you prefer.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you, i will try that